# How to check if a variable is val or var programmatically?

Tags: scala, variables, definition

In scala, we can define variable like:
`val a=10` or `var a=10`.

Is there anyway we can check if a is a `val` or `var` programmatically?

Comment: Any solution to this would probably need to use macros or reflection. Do you have a use case in mind?

Comment: Give use-case for that. On compile time you have such knowledge, and in scala there is no way to simply abstract that.

Comment: Not any particular use case, I just started to pick up, and want to know what can or cannot do in scala.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala is an object-oriented language. This means, in particular, that you can only manipulate objects.

Variables are not objects in Scala (like pretty much every programming language), therefore there is no way that you could, for example, call a method on a variable to ask it whether it is a `var` or a `val` (because you can only call methods on objects, and variables aren't objects), and there is no way to pass a variable to a method to ask the method whether the variable is a `val` or a `var` (because you can only pass objects as arguments, and variables aren't objects).

Again, this is not really specific to Scala, this applies to the overwhelming majority of programming languages. Even in programming languages like Ruby with very powerful dynamic meta programming capabilities, variables aren't objects and cannot be reflected upon.

But wait, you might say, classes aren't objects in Scala either, but I can get a runtime representation of a class using [`scala.Predef.classof[T]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#classOf[T]:Class[T])! Indeed you can, but there is a fundamental difference between classes and variables: classes are *runtime* entities, so even if they don't exist as objects, they *do* at least *exist* at runtime. Variables are a pure *compile time* construct, they *do not exist* at runtime.

So, *the only way* you can get at a variable *at all* is using *compile-time reflection*. Which, very likely, is complete overkill for whatever it is that you want to do.

So, to answer your question:

> Is there anyway we can check if a is a `val` or `var` programmatically?

*Extremely short answer*: No.

*Very short answer*: You shouldn't use `var` anyway. If you follow that advice, the question becomes moot.

*Short answer*: If your local variable scopes are so big and convoluted that you cannot even figure out whether a variable is a `var` or a `val` you have much bigger problems.

*Simple answer*: No.

*Slightly more elaborate answer*: No, not at runtime.

*Very complex answer*: It is probably possible using [*Compile-Time Reflection*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html#compile-time-reflection).